# How do I properly test my database performance with high load demand?

Tags: database-performance, sybase-asa

I have found a lot of topics about stress-testing web application.

My goals are different, it's to test only database (sybase sql anywhere 9).

**What I need:**

- Some tool to give a diagnostic of all sqls and find a bottleneck. I wish I could macro-view the entire system easily.
- Best practices to design/build a good sql queries.

**The system issues are:**

- 20GB database size.
- 2-5 request per second
- Thousands sql spread in the code (this messy can be solved only rewriting the system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

several open source tools are listed here:

http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way would actually be to upgrade your SQL Anywhere to v10 or (better) v11, as the latest releases include a complete performance diagnostic toolset. See the documentation [here](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101en/dbusage_en11/perform-s-4478058.html) for more details.